# How to Optimize Query with Lots of Aggregates

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

How do I optimize this query? Right now, it's running too slow ~10s. Full details below:

```
SELECT ProjectName, 
       Actuals_YTD, 
       Rem_Forecast, 
       Total_Forecast, 
       Approved_Budget, 
       Variance, 
       Variance_Percentage, 
       ProjectComments, 
       VersionType, 
       ModifiedDate 
FROM (SELECT pd.ProjectId, 
             pd.ProjectName, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) <= '06/01/2011' THEN feb.USDactualamount ELSE 0.0 END) AS Actuals_YTD, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) > '06/01/2011' THEN feb.forecastusd ELSE 0.0 END) AS Rem_Forecast, 
             ((SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) <= '06/01/2011' THEN feb.USDactualamount ELSE 0.0 END)) + (SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) > '06/01/2011' then feb.forecastusd else 0.0 end))) AS Total_Forecast, 
             SUM(COALESCE((feb.REVISEDPLANUSD),0)) AS Approved_Budget, 
             ((SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) <= '06/01/2011' THEN feb.USDactualamount ELSE 0.0 END)) + (SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) > '06/01/2011' then feb.forecastusd else 0.0 end))) - ((SUM(COALESCE((feb.REVISEDPLANUSD),0)))) AS Variance, 
             CASE WHEN (SUM(COALESCE((feb.REVISEDPLANUSD),0))) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE ((((((SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(base.ProjectMonth) <= '06/01/2011' THEN feb.USDactualamount else 0.0 end)) + (SUM(CASE WHEN RPD.PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE(projectmonth) > '06/01/2011' then feb.forecastusd else 0.0 end)))) - (SUM(COALESCE((feb.REVISEDPLANUSD),0)))) / (SUM(COALESCE((feb.REVISEDPLANUSD),0)))) * 100) END AS Variance_Percentage, 
             pd.ProjectAux1, 
             pd.ProjectComments, 
             pd.VersionType, 
             MAX(base.ModifiedDate) AS ModifiedDate 
      FROM rpd.ProjectDetail pd  INNER JOIN rpd.FundSource fs ON pd.FundSourceId = fs.FundSourceId  
                                 INNER JOIN rpd.Baseline base ON pd.ProjectId = base.ProjectId  
                                 INNER JOIN rpd.FundEntityBaseline feb ON feb.BaselineId = base.BaselineId  
      GROUP BY pd.ProjectAux1, pd.ProjectId, pd.ProjectName, pd.ProjectComments, pd.VersionType)
WHERE VersionType Like '%Text%' WITH UR
```

Here's the schema of 3 tables (FundSource is not included as it only has ~200 rows and I think it's pretty negligible)

Schema:

[image: FundEntityBaseline]
[image: ProjectDetail]
[image: Baseline]

Rows:

- FundEntityBaseline: 354603
- Baseline: 80208
- ProjectDetail: 1813

Indices on ProjectDetail:

- 1 Index for Primary Key (ProjectId)
- 1 Index for Foreign Key (FundSourceId)
- 1 Index for SELECT/GROUP BY containing columns (ProjectAux1,
  ProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectComments, VersionType)
- 1 Index with (VersionType, ProjectName)

Indices on Baseline:

- 1 Index for Primary Key (BaselineId)
- 1 Index for Foreign Key (ProjectId)
- 1 Index with (ProjectTeamId, ProjectMonth)
- 1 Index with ProjectMonth only

Indices on FundEntityBaseline

- 1 Index for Primary Key (FundEntityBaselineId)
- 1 Index for Foreign Key (BaselineId)

Latest access plan:
[image: Access Plan]

Comment: Can you show the source of the PROJECTMONTH_TO_DATE funtion/procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Move the where clause (WHERE VersionType Like '%Text%) on line up so it will be in the inner SQL statement. The way it is now, your query will first make all possible joins and then filter that complete set with the where clause.

So your statement will be like

```
WHERE pd.VersionType Like '%Text%'
GROUP BY .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Put (=recreate) your indexes in a tablespace with a page size of 32K - if not already configured so.